# Verifying content of Variable from User Tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have this user tags that hold values of diffrent fields from database and are used to display those datas in HTML table

```
<td data-label="Names" class="wppb-name">{{meta_first_name}} {{meta_last_name}}</td>
<td data-label="Gender" class="wppb-gender">{{meta_Gender}} </td>
<td data-label="Department" class="wppb-department">{{meta_Department}}</td>
<td data-label="Position Title" class="wppb-position_title">{{meta_position_title}}</td>
<td data-label="Region" class="wppb-region">{{meta_region}}</td>
<td data-label="District" class="wppb-district_dar">
```

Then I have this simple PHP Code which check for value of particular tag and perform task according to the value that will be found

Here I want to check value of Region if it is Nairobi

```
<?php
$region = {{meta_region}};

if ($region == "Nairobi") {
  echo "<h2>Its a Kenya!</h2>";
} else {
  echo "<h2>Its another Region!</h2>";
}
?>
```

But if I execute above code it hide all the data's in HTML Table

Any idea how can i implement this?

UPDATE 
Now it displaying this error

```
Fatal error: Method PB_Mustache_Generate_Template::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\watumishi\wp-content\plugins\profile-builder-pro\add-ons\user-listing\userlisting.php on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**CHANGE YOUR PHP CODE TO:**

```
<?php
$region = {{meta_region}};

if ($region == "Nairobi") {
  $ans = "Its a Kenya!";
} else {
  $ans = "Its another Region!";
}
?>
```

**NOW WRITE YOUR HTML AS:**

```
<td data-label="Region" class="wppb-region"><h2><?php echo $ans;?></h2></td>
```

Comment: It still return nothing (hide all data of that column).

Comment: Now it bring this error `Fatal error: Method PB_Mustache_Generate_Template::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\watumishi\wp-content\plugins\profile-builder-pro\add-ons\user-listing\userlisting.php on line 0`